# Import TMDB3 package in django views

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I'm trying to use IMDB3 to get some info on movies, but I can't import the package. The same happens with this other wrapper https://github.com/doganaydin/themoviedb/.

When I try to import the tmdb3 package in views.py, I get an `ImportError: No module named 'tmdb_api'`

How could I import tmdb3 into my project?

My django app is in `D:/Bureau/Django/DVDDB/DVDataBase`. Python is installed in `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\`

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.9.3 (installed with pip) on Windows 10.

Here's the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002C415E752F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Bureau\Django\DVDDB\DVDDB\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('DVDataBase.urls')),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Bureau\Django\DVDDB\DVDataBase\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\Bureau\Django\DVDDB\DVDataBase\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tmdb3
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\tmdb3\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tmdb_api import Configuration, searchMovie, searchMovieWithYear, \
ImportError: No module named 'tmdb_api'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [pytmdb3](https://github.com/wagnerrp/pytmdb3) does not support Python 3. You could try [tmdbsimple](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tmdbsimple) instead, which appears to support Python 2. Your other options are to switch to Python 2 (not ideal) or update pytmdb3 to support Python 3.

The specific error is from this line in `tmdb3\__init__.py`

```
from tmdb_api import Configuration, searchMovie, searchMovieWithYear, \
```

For Python 3, this should be either

```
from tmdb.tmdb_api import Configuration, searchMovie, searchMovieWithYear, \
```

or

```
from .tmdb_api import Configuration, searchMovie, searchMovieWithYear, \
```

However, you will probably get other errors once you change that line.

Comment: Ugh, forgot to check Python 3 compatibility. Indeed, it's not according to [this issue](https://github.com/wagnerrp/pytmdb3/issues/18). I'll be more careful to check that next time, thanks :)